# How to display correct local time on view ticket page in fossil

Tags: fossil

I see the ticket view page display like

```
username added on 2015-10-29 08:51:00:
```

In fact, it should be 2015-10-29 16:51:00:

My time zone is GMT+8, so I changed the view ticket from

```
...
query {SELECT datetime(tkt_mtime) AS xdate, login AS xlogin,
...
html " added on $xdate:\n"
...
```

To

```
...
query {SELECT datetime(tkt_mtime+8/24) AS xdate, login AS xlogin,
...
html " added on $xdate:\n"
...
```

But, it won't work.

Comment: In fact, if the 8/24 modified as 8/24.0, it works but ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: "it won't work" is not a good description of your problem. You're much more likely to get (effective) help if you describe what exactly goes wrong; what you expected to happen, what did happen, and what message appeared.

That said...

Use `SELECT datetime(tkt_mtime, 'localtime') as xdate` to convert utc to your local time zone.

Check out SQLite's documentation on [date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more info.